# Question about FMCW range-velocity plot

Tags: matlab, fft, radar, frequency-modulation, doppler

I am working on plotting range-velocity heatmap of the receiving FMCW signal. I actually have already plotted. However, I do not really understand the mapping relationship between Doppler FFT bin and velocity. I learned to map from 1d FFT bin to range with the following codes as the x-axis.

```
x = (0:ADCsample-1) - ADCsample/2;
x = x*Fs/ADCsample;
% freq to dist;
x = x*3e8/2/slope;
```

Some notes, I plot the 2D FFT with nFFT = No of chirp in one frame =64.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, because the speed can be positive and negative (meaning approaching to and going from sensor if target is moving), you need to shift your doppler indices from [0, N-1] to
[-N/2,N/2 - 1] by simple subtraction by N. Then you just multiply scale [-N/2,N/2-1] by:

```
lambda/(2*N*T_rpi)
```

where:
- `lambda` is wavelength for your FMCW radar (`lambda = c/Fc`, c - speed of light and Fc central transmit frequency of chirp - for 77-81GHz you would use 79GHz)
- `N` is number of chirps transmitted
- `T_rpi` is chirp repetion interval (meaning `T_active + T_idle` if you have idle time after chirp transmission)

If you use multiple transmitters in time division multiplexed mode, you would need to multiple by:

```
lambda/(2*N*T_rpi*n_tx)
```

You then gain scale in m/s.